# AutoForm Plugin for QGIS 3.6

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-3

I cannot find the AutoForm plugin. I am using QGIS 3.6, have this plugin perhaps given another name, or where do I find the functionality.

I am trying to create lookup tables following this tutorial
https://blog.sourcepole.ch/2017/02/10/autoform-plugin-for-qgis/

Comment: Unfortunately that [plugin is outdated](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoForm/) and only available for QGIS 2.14 onwards. It hasn't been updated for QGIS 3. You could try contacting the author on their [GitHub page](https://github.com/sourcepole/AutoForm) or attempt to update the plugin yourself using the new QGIS 3 API.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Unfortunately, I will not be able able to update the plugin due to limited capacity. I left an issue notice and hoping one of the developers can assist.